# fetch datas from PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created two tables in a PostgreSQL database named `doctor` and `department`. I have used `dept_id` as foreign key in the `doctor` table. Now I have listed the departments in Eclipse but when I'm clicking a department the doctors in the particular table should be listed. So I request you to please provide me code for getting the `doctor_list` from the `doctor` table. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You'll have to provide more details, like what language you are using, what code you have used so far, etc. Eclipse is just a tool that can be used with Java, C, Python, SQL, ... Then, the question might be migrated to SO.

Answer (score 0):

**Create the tables**

```
create table Department (
dept_id serial primary key, 
dept_name text);

create table Doctor (
id serial primary key, 
name text not null, 
dept_id integer references Department (dept_id)
);
```

**Add the data**

```
insert into department(dept_name) values('Main dept');
insert into department(dept_name) values('Another dept');
insert into doctor(name, dept_id) values('Adam', 1);
insert into doctor(name, dept_id) values('Eva', 2);
```

Simple query to get list of doctors for a particular department.

```
select * from doctor where dept_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using Java (if not, then ignore this answer), and you are making simple java application (not Java EE) you have to firstly make a connection to database. 
[This tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/) will show you how to do it. then you have to use it. [Here](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jdbc/sample-java-jdbc-program-connect-database) is explained how to do it (with making connection again).

Modyfying code from second link your could look something like:

```
private void LoadDoctors(Connection conn, LinkedList listOfBlogs)
  {
    try 
    {
      Statement st = conn.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT d.id as \"did\",d.name as \"dnme\",dd.id as \"ddid\",dd.name as \"ddname\" FROM doctors d JOIN departments dd ON dd.id=d.dept_id ORDER BY id");
      while ( rs.next() )
      {
        Doctor doc= new Doctor ();
        doc.id        = rs.getInt("did");
        doc.name= rs.getString("dname");
        doc.department= new Department(rs.getInt("ddid"),rs.getInt("ddname"));
        list.add(doc);
      }
      rs.close();
      st.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException se) {
      System.err.println("Threw a SQLException creating the list of blogs.");
      System.err.println(se.getMessage());
    }
  }
```